# Checking HTTPURLConnection response without closing

Tags: android, file-upload, httpurlconnection

Is there a way to check the HTTPURLConnection response without closing the connection in Android?

**Why?**

I have a setup where by large files are sent through a load balancer to a backend.  When an upload starts, it can resume at the last offset.

In order to make sure that clients can resume uploads, the load balancer times connections out after a short period, which sends an EOF to the backend server, which then stops reading and saves the data sent up to that point, unlocking the file, and allowing the client to try again.  The load balancer sends an error code to the client.

However, on mobile networks sometimes the connection remains open but very slow, so the data keeps getting dumped to the load balancer, but not forwarded to the backend server after the timeout.

**Goal** 
My goal is to see if I got a response from the load balancer in my app, and to restart the upload if I did.